# How to make an automatic script run every day on my server host?

Tags: php, shell, unix

Is that possible to make an automatic script on my server host ? I don't have access to the prompt.

I would like to do a script who remove files in a specific directory every weeks.

Comment: Have a look at the manual page from `cron`.

Comment: I don't have but I would like. And what have you tried so far which turned out to not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight answer is: use [CRON](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Since you don't have "access to the prompt", you're probably using some kind of shared hosting (right?). In that case, most hosting providers offer a UI interface for CRON. In HostGator, for example, it's called "Cron Jobs".